# Implementation of Firebase with laravel to send notification in android app

Tags: php, android, laravel, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Basically I am making APIS in laravel for my android app ,so I want to notify users when admin create new task for them, I have a little bit confusion about generation of device token  like what will be the process for that? I have created a device token field in users table but don't know how the device token will be generated I want to store the device token  on my database when user register on my app.
THIS IS MY NOTIFICATION FUNCTION

`

```
public function sendWebNotification()
    {
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $FcmToken = User::whereNotNull('device_key')->pluck('device_key')->all();


         $user=User::whereNotNull('device_key')->value('name');

        $serverKey = 'AAAAqLMsLGU:APA91bF0MWybbBdXcLOV9MlS4sLeHgPgSt14xEsWOdLMf76eqvpqIFYGicI6S0TWwUVfjEkrtVOwNympmZIIATCmaYpiSknfROjzhXKjDX86bzxhvltByi3AUUfL-g2laZ9SpG4Uft8F'
        ;

        $data = [
            "registration_ids" => $FcmToken,
            "notification" => [
                "title" => "hello". $user,
                "body" => "sndjjsdjjd",
            ]
        ];
   

       $encodedData = json_encode($data);

        $headers = [
            'Authorization:key=' . $serverKey,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encodedData);

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        // FCM response
        dd($result);
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A unique device token is generated on each device/app combination (often referred to as an app instance) that intends to receive messages from Firebase Cloud Messaging.

If you want to target such individual app instances, you send this token from the app to your server-side database, and retrieve it from there when you need to send a message to the app instance.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [accessing the device registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register). The `sendRegistrationToServer` in the code samples, is a place holder for code you will need to implement to send the token to the server/database.

Answer (score 0):

Except that you query a [`Model`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html), this has little to do with Laravel, because Laravel commonly supports [notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications) and countless [channels](https://laravel-notification-channels.com/about/); better try to use the [FCM Notification Channel](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/fcm):

```
composer require kreait/laravel-firebase
composer require laravel-notification-channels/fcm:~2.0
```

This requires [`laravel-firebase`](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase#configuration) and a Google service-account JSON. Then one can also use these FCM classes directly:
https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-messaging.html

---

That (strangely named) "device_key" might be the token the client gets when logging in to FCM.

Comment: @Cideinit And i'm not looking to fix your code, especially when it can be easily installed. So what exactly is the point in using a framework and then ignoring the framework?